# MomentJS not working when using setInterval method

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js to convert the timestamp to readable form like "8 minutes ago"!

I am using setInterval to update the code every 1 second to update the time dynamically but it's not working at all. Help me!

Code:

```js
let timer = () => {
  let time = document.getElementsByClassName('timeago');

  for(let i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    time[i].innerText = moment(time[i].innerText, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss").tz("Asia/Kathmandu").fromNow();
  }
};
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="timeago">2018-05-15 09:21:00</span>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After you update the `innerText` of your element the first time, how do you expect to parse it as `"YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss"` on the next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing the text of the element as a string (and telling `moment` to interpret it according to "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss") every time the function runs. Instead, save the moment only once, and on an interval, calculate the difference between it and now.

You also need to ask Moment to format it properly. Your element has `09:21:00` but the Moment format string is `h:mm:ss` - that won't work in case of two-digit hours.

```js
const timeagoSpan = document.querySelector('.timeago');
const from = moment(timeagoSpan.textContent, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
let timer = () => {
  timeagoSpan.textContent = from.fromNow();
};
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="timeago">2018-05-14 22:21:00</span>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh! Got the logic. Thanks, dude!